# Spacing between figure and text

Tags: figure, spacing

I'm writing my thesis using latex and normally there are figures and texts. For figures, I use [h] to place the float here. If the paragraph after the figure is not enough to fill the whole page, Latex makes a gap between the figure and the text to fill the whole page, see the attached image. It seems for me latex starts to fill the page from the bottom to the top. I'm using Overleaf.

The code
I actually used normal subfigures code between the texts

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\hspace*{-0.5cm}
\begin{subfigure}{a\textwidth}
\centering \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{Figures/Overpotential} 
\end{subfigure} 
\begin{subfigure}{b\textwidth} 
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{Figures/Overpotential vs         peakcurrents} 
\end{subfigure}
\caption{(a) Changes of the ov-------.} 
\label{Overpotential}
\end{figure}
```

Regards

[image]

Comment: Please include the Latex code you have.

Comment: I actually used normal subfigures code between the texts  
      \begin{figure}[H]
  \hspace*{-0.5cm}
  \begin{subfigure}{a\textwidth}
        \centering
         \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{Figures/Overpotential}  
\end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{b\textwidth}
        \centering
         \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{Figures/Overpotential vs peakcurrents}
 \end{subfigure}
       \caption{(a) Changes of the ov-------.}
       \label{Overpotential}
      \end{figure}

Comment: To make it better readable, edit your question to include the code in a code block and with proper linebreaks, so it is readable.
I'm not working with LaTex, so I can't help you here, but it will increase your chance to get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Write \raggedbottom into the preamble.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).